# Make a vegan classic poutine

Tags: veganism, dairy-substitutes, recipe-request

I am a huge fan of poutine. Since poutine isn't very vegan, but I love it, it stops me from being a vegan. So, to fix that, is there an easy vegan-friendly poutine recipe? I would try searching from the internet but I'm afraid it might just be wasting my time in choosing a good one.

Answer (score 8):

I found plenty of resources online:

Vegan poutine:
https://itdoesnttastelikechicken.com/the-ultimate-vegan-poutine/

Vegan Mozzarella
https://gourmandelle.com/how-to-make-stretchy-vegan-mozzarella-cheese/

Vegan Gravy
https://www.connoisseurusveg.com/vegan-gravy/

Mix it up and you are done. 
For the poutine, you can also dice some champignons and brown them with the onions (I think, that mushrooms give that earthy flavor). Some parsley is also nice, but I don't want to insult Canadians.

For the mozzarella: I don't think that cashew mozzarella is a worthy cheese replacement. In Switzerland we have a dish called raclette (its just melted cheese with side stuff). To imitate this "tart"(???) cheese flavor, I like to use cheese made out of lupins.

Or maybe you could try some vegan nacho cheese slices.
https://www.veganricha.com/2014/09/nut-free-vegan-nacho-cheese-slices.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: "Some parsley is also nice, but I don't want to insult Canadians."   Why would that be insulting to Canadians?